# Find nearest neighbor between meshgrid of lats and lons

Tags: python, nearest-neighbor

Let's say I have a Polar dataset in which I run a projection on to get latitude and longitude values:

```
# Convert to Cartesian
x = allrange * np.sin(np.deg2rad(azimuth))[:,None]
y = allrange * np.cos(np.deg2rad(azimuth))[:,None]
dataproj = Proj(f"+proj=stere +lat_0={latitude} +lat_ts={latitude} +lon_0={longitude} +ellps=WGS84 +units=m")
Alons,Alats = dataproj(x,y,inverse=True)
```

This outputs a 2D grid of Alons, and a 2D grid of Alats that are both the same shape x or y. I also have a dataset that is the same shape as x, or y, in which I want to extract values from. This can be thought of as the third axis of data (or z).

Now let's say I want to find the nearest neighbor within these Alats and Alons grid to some latitude and longitude, say [30,-100], and extract the value from z corresponding to that nearest neighbor position. The code that I have developed to do this would be:

```
tmp_x = (np.abs(30 - Alats)).argmin()
tmp_y = (np.abs(-130 - Alons)).argmin()
```

The problem is that this returns a 2D grid for tmp_x as well as tmp_y. Therefore, I cannot index z[tmp_x,tmp_y].

What would be the better / correct way of approaching this problem to be able to index z based on the nearest neighbor of some arbitrary lat/lon from a known grid of lat/lons? I know one can use the 'RegularGridInterpolator' from Scipy, but that does not work here because the Alats and Alons are not strictly ascending or descending and are 2D.